# Undefined method error for Edit Profile form? (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, models

I'm trying to make an edit profile option for my user. One of the params I pass into the form ":name" won't work - where do I define :name so my form can take it and update the user ?
"NoMethodError at /users/3/edit
undefined method `name' for #"

My users controller:

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :require_login, only: [:new, :create]
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if current_user
      @comment = @user.comments.build
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :handle, :avatar)
  end
end
```

User Model :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  authenticates_with_sorcery!



  validates :email, :handle, :name, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  validates :password, confirmation: true
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
  has_many :game_players, foreign_key: :player_id
  has_many :games, through: :game_players
  has_many :comments

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100#" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  def total_wins
    self.games.where.not(winner_id: nil).where(winner_id: self.id).count
  end

  def total_games
    self.games.where.not(winner_id: nil).count
  end

  def total_losses
    total_games - total_wins
  end

  def win_rate
    total_games != 0 ? total_wins / total_games.to_f : 0
  end
end
```

Form:

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
  .field
    = f.label :email
    = f.text_field :email
  .field
    = f.label :gender
    = f.password_field :gender
  .field
    = f.label :location
    = f.password_field :location
  .field
    = f.label :bio
    %br/
    = f.password_field :bio
  = f.file_field :avatar
  %br/
  = f.submit "Update"
```

Please note I don't have a separate profile model/controller - I'm just using a user/edit view under the User model.

I tried adding :name to the schema and it didn't work. As you can see I'm new to this and your help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: do you have `name` field in your `users` database table?

Comment: in the schema? ya i put t.string "name" and it still doesn't work. i dont have an edit/create user migration tho, i used sorcery. should i add :name to a sorcery file or something?

Answer (score 2):

> I tried adding :name to the schema and it didn't work.

Just to make things clear: you should **never** change `schema.rb` file manually, as it just contains an overview of underlying database structure, but has no impact on it. In case you want to change your database structure you should use migrations (read [this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) carefully).

As you've already mentioned you used `Sorcery` gem, so the problem seems quite obvious now: its generator defines only `email`, `password` and `salt` attributes (as I see from [here](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/blob/master/lib/generators/sorcery/templates/migration/core.rb)).

What you should do now is to generate a rails migration to add all other required fields to your `User` model manually. Fortunately Rails have built-in method to do this kind of things:

```
rails g migration AddNameToUser name:string
```

Executing this in your shell would create a migration file. Running it with `rake db:migrate` would add `name` field to `User` model (and update `schema.rb` for you).

Answer (score 0):

Your User Schema should have a name attribute, just like you have for email, avatar, and so on . Hit you rails console and run `User.new` and verify that name is one of the attributes. Then in your User controller add name as a permitted params.

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :handle, :avatar, :name)
end
```

Notice I included :name as one of the permitted params

Comment: You're right name isn't there - how do I manually add name through the console? (sorry for being a nooby booby) thanks so much!!!!!!!

Comment: You can't add a name attribute to User from the console. If User had a name attribute, you could change the VALUE of the attribute from the console. follow twonegatives advise to add a name attribute to your User Table.